# Adding Comments in oB

Tags: sphero-api

I don't see comments implemented in the orbBasic doc, and the Visual Basic ' mark doesn't work.  So, I'm guessing we don't have the ability to comment our code yet?  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter on Sphero does not currently handle comments. You could manually pre-process your programs by removing the comments and sending the result to the ball.